# Working with selectors assigned to variables after a .load()

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hello">
    <span id="world">Hello!</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $hello = $('#hello'),    // Assigning frequently used
    $world = $('#world');    // selectors to variables.

$hello.children().fadeOut(250, function() {
    $hello.load('other.html #hello > *', function() {
        $world.fadeIn(250);    // This now references nothing...
    });
});
```

**other.html**

```
<div id="hello">
    <span id="world">Something completely different...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's 'cause your `.load()` call on the `#hello` element replaces its contents after the AJAX call, obliterating the original `#world` element child.

The new `#world` child is a completely different element than the original `#world` child, and as such, is not "selected" in your original jQuery cache. You'll most probably need to select again, or (probably better) just call `.load()` on the `#world` element instead (and change the AJAX response to cater to that change as well).

Comment: Well said. I like your answer better. :)

Comment: @richardneililagan ~ The example uses one child element but I use the catch-all `#element > *` because each page is different and may have one or many different elements. Thus, the idea of using `.load()` on the `#world` element directly would not work dynamically as I need.

Comment: The `.load()` function replaces the `#hello` element, so I believe the `> *` is not doing  anything.

Comment: @benjibee ~ then you're probably limited to having to select again ... unless you can work around it depending on what you want to do. If you're only wanting to fade in the new content, you may want to try `$hello.children().fadeIn()` or some derivative.

Comment: @Chris ~ the `> *` in the `.load()` call references the returned HTML from the AJAX call, not the one on the DOM itself, so I guess it should be good ... as long as there's a valid `#hello > *` on the returned HTML result.

Comment: I'm sorry. I read it so fast, I put the `> *` on the wrong side of the equation. I still think that string of characters is redundant, as the (API)[http://api.jquery.com/load/] leads me to believe that `$hello.load('other.html #hello, ...)` would be sufficient. Or in this case, `$hello.load('other.html #world', ...)` would prevent two elements with `id="hello"`.

Comment: @Chris May ~ In the given example, this would be true, yes. But the various pages it would load will contain multiple and different types of elements. Using `#element > * ` not only prevents duplicating the referenced element (as it grabs it's children, and not the element itself) but also allows me to grab the entire contents of the `<div>` dynamically depending on the contents.

Answer (score 0):

use either jquery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or add jquery files after all html files being loaded.

Comment: ~ As far as I know, `.live()` only works with events performed on the selector. I'm simply looking to maintain the variable as a reference after page load.

Comment: I don't know how you trigger load, so I also wrote live. Then add javascript codes related to that new doms generated beneath each loaded html files. I do it that way when live() does not cover what I need.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `$world = $('#world')`, it references that specific `<div>` element. When you ran .load() to overwrite the `<div#world>`, that element was no longer there, even though it was replaced by another `<div#world>`

Comment: ~ Yeah, I understand that idea. As it stands now I simply re-assign the relevant selectors to their variables after the `.load()` to prevent the rest of my code from breaking by referencing hundreds of stale variables. I guess I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @BenjiBee I've been thinking the same thing... that there should be a more elegant solution, like how `.live()` and `.delegate()` work, as @Arda mentioned. Hmmm...

Comment: Looking at (jQuery's FAQ)[http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Using_event_rebinding], it looks like refreshing your variables is the best option. Maybe it would be somewhat more elegant to refresh them in a callback function from the `.load()`.

Comment: ~ Yeah, that is what I've gone with. Where I had a list of variables and selectors defined at the beginning of my script I now have a function in it's place so I can re-initialize them when I load in a new page. I sure wish I could simply call some kind of function on a variable that would have it update itself by grabbing the ID from the DOM again!